# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '500')

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, undefined

I am making a discord bot that is a currency system, and I am having issues with the command to transfer the currency between users.

It is reading the correct amount that you put in the command with the format:

!transfer @tag amount

It seems to be getting everything correctly, including the amount that I type in, but I am not sure how to correct this error. For example if I use the command !transfer @tag 500, it returns

transferAmount = message.content.parseInt[args[2]];
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '500')

This is the relevant code

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}transfer`)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        var transferAmount = 0;
        transferAmount = message.content.parseInt[args[2]];
        currency.add(getUserFromMention(message.content).id, transferAmount);
        console.log(getUserFromMention(message.content));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried checking that args is indeed a array of length 3. It seems to me like args[2] is giving undefined, meaning the args might not be parsed correctly and missing an element

Comment: well it's identifying the correct input

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, as I am pretty dumb.

`transferAmount = message.content.parseInt[args[2]];`

needed to be changed to

`transferAmount = args[2];`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have want to repalce:

```
transferAmount = message.content.parseInt[args[2]];
```

with:

```
transferAmount = parseInt(args[2]);
```

as `parseInt` is not a property of your `message.content` (which is a string by the way), but a native Node.js function.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for more information.